# user permission Typo3 : disable the creation of new objects in my extension by some BE groups, leaving only the possibility to modify

Tags: typo3

I wrote my Typo3 Extension,
I created a BE group that has permissions on my extension
I would like to know how to "remove" the possibility of adding new records (model objects) to my extension (NEW function, in list mode in my sys_folder containing the list of model object of my extension), leaving the possibility of modifying existing objects unchanged.

Thank you in advance for any solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible - because there are logical reasons against it.

If an editor is allowed to fully modify a "product XY", he is also allowed (and it is *possible* for him) to modify all properties so "product XY" is getting a "product A". Modifying a record allows you to build a totally other record on the origin base. The only leaving property would be the UID of the record.

Comment: Thank you for the answer : 
All object (eg product XY) are built from a JSON service, and some php code (by Task and scheduler). 
I would need to allow editors only the possibility to intervene to modify some fields, if this intervention is deemed necessary, and I cannot do it on the JSON data source

Answer (score 0):

Solution (add in Page TSConfig) :

```
mod.web_list {
        deniedNewTables = "My Extension Table"
}
```